# terraform to create cloudwatch event for RDS to trigger lambda

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I would like to run an AWS lambda function when RDS instance get reboot or stop. 
I am exploring to create cloudwatch event, whenever the RDS instance get reboot or stop, it should trigger my lambda function.

**How can I setup this using terraform. I have used below method to try but its failing to execute.**

```
provider "aws" 
{
    access_key = ""
    secret_key = ""
version = "~> 2.10"
    region = "ap-southeast-1"
}
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "test-RDS-event" {
  name = "test-RDS-event"
  description = "Capture RDS event for lambda target"
  event_pattern = <<pattern
  {
    "source": [
      "aws.rds"
      ],
      "detail-type": [
        "RDS DB Instance Event"
      ],
      "detail": {
        "EventCategories": [
          "failover"
        ]
      }

  }
pattern
}
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "lambda" {
  rule = "${aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.test-RDS-event.name}"
  target_id = "populate_NLB_TG_with_RDS"
  arn = "${aws_cloudwatch_event_target.lambda.arn}"
  }
```

I am getting below error when I execute this and i am not sure what need to set to fix the error.

> C:\Terraform>terraform.exe plan
>
> Error: aws_cloudwatch_event_target.lambda:
>   aws_cloudwatch_event_target.lambda: self reference not allowed:
>   "aws_cloudwatch_event_target.lambda.arn"

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "test-RDS-event" {
  name = "test-RDS-event"
  description = "Capture RDS event for lambda target"
  event_pattern = <<pattern
  {
    "source": [
      "aws.rds"
      ],      "detail-type": [
        "RDS DB Instance Event"
      ],      "detail": {
        "EventCategories": [
          "failover"        ]      }    }
pattern }
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "lambda" {
  rule = "${aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.test-RDS-event.name}"
  target_id = "populate_NLB_TG_with_RDS"
  arn = "${aws_lambda_function.populate_NLB_TG_with_RDS}" }

Comment: i have wrote above and when i try to init i am getting error below

Error: Error loading C:\Terraform\example.tf: Error reading config for aws_cloudwatch_event_target[lambda]: aws_lambda_function.populate_NLB_TG_with_RDS: resource variables must be three parts: TYPE.NAME.ATTR in:

${aws_lambda_function.populate_NLB_TG_with_RDS}

Comment: You should edit your question to include the Terraform code rather than putting it in an unformatted comment.

Comment: Hi, 
sorry, i am very new to this portal and programming, so i was not so sure. 
i have updated the code and the error which i am getting. 
any suggestion on the above.

Answer (score 0):

in the provided code you don't create a lambda function and as a result - don't use lambda's arn. it should be something similar to:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "rds-events" {
  filename = "${data.archive_file.start_scheduler.output_path}"
  function_name = "rds-events"
  ...
} 

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "lambda" {
  rule = "${aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.test-RDS-event.name}"
  target_id = "populate_NLB_TG_with_RDS"
  arn = "${aws_lambda_function.rds-events.arn}"
}
```